# High availability deployment with Ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm using Ansible to deploy pairs of NGinx/Tomcat instances and I'm trying to improve availability during deployment.

A logical instance is 1 NGinx + 1 Tomcat: I have 4 logical instances spread over 2 distant locations (see hosts file bellow).

I launch one playbook called deploy.xml which looks like this:

```
- hosts: ngx-servers
  pre_tasks:
    - include: tasks/remove-server.yml
  roles:
    - role: ngx-server

- hosts: app-servers
  roles:
    - role: app-server

- hosts: ngx-servers
  tasks:
    - include: tasks/add-server.yml
```

What I want is to deploy 50% of my 4 logical instances before deploying the others (and stop everything if something goes wrong).
One solution could be targeting montigny-app-servers/montigny-ngx-servers first (instead of app-servers/ngx-servers) and then the second location but I would need to duplicate playbook content (and so on if I need to add other server locations).

Any idea to make it properly ?

Here is my hosts file:

```
#
# Serveurs d'application
#

# Montigny
[montigny-app-servers]
mo-app-server-1 ansible_ssh_host=1y.domain.fr ansible_ssh_user=devops
mo-app-server-2 ansible_ssh_host=2y.domain.fr ansible_ssh_user=devops

# Bievre
[bievre-app-servers]
bi-app-server-1 ansible_ssh_host=1b.domain.fr ansible_ssh_user=devops
bi-app-server-2 ansible_ssh_host=2b.domain.fr ansible_ssh_user=devops

# Tous
[app-servers:children]
montigny-app-servers
bievre-app-servers

#
# Serveurs NGinx
#

# Montigny
[montigny-ngx-servers]
mo-ngx-server-1 ansible_ssh_host=1y.domain.fr ansible_ssh_user=devops
mo-ngx-server-2 ansible_ssh_host=2y.domain.fr ansible_ssh_user=devops

# Bievre
[bievre-ngx-servers]
bi-ngx-server-1 ansible_ssh_host=1b.domain.fr ansible_ssh_user=devops
bi-ngx-server-2 ansible_ssh_host=2b.domain.fr ansible_ssh_user=devops

# Tous
[ngx-servers:children]
montigny-ngx-servers
bievre-ngx-servers
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> One solution could be targeting montigny-app-servers/montigny-ngx-servers first (instead of app-servers/ngx-servers) and then the second location

This is what we do, couple changes:

Add geolocated groups:

```
[Montigny-servers:children]
montigny-app-servers
montigny-ngx-servers

[bievre-servers:children]
bievre-app-servers
bievre-ngx-servers
```

Then you can execute you playbook on the subsets with the options -l/--limnit

```
$ ansible-playbooks -i inventory site.yml -l Montigny-servers && \
  ansible-playbooks -i inventory site.yml -l bievre-servers
```

this way it will first run you logical instances from Montigny, and if everything went fine (exit 0), it will run the playbook for bievre instances

Find more exemples:
http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_best_practices.html#what-this-organization-enables-examples

Comment: You are right, except that it needs to call ansible-playbooks twice, which is not very nice :S

Comment: That is the way ansible describe in its best practices (see linke). 
Otherwise 'keba' as your solution to run it in one playbook

Comment: OK, you convince me with your solution, this is the easier one. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the idea of putting your hosts in separate groups so that you can run commands on first one group and then the other.

You should be able to put that in one playbook though - if you create the fundamental actions in an include script, you can then create a playbook that will have multiple '- hosts' sections, each of which will call the include script.

That would look something like:

```
---
- hosts: firstgroupname
  tasks:
    - include: pathandnameofincludescript.yaml
- hosts: secondgroupname
  tasks:
    - include: pathandnameofincludescript.yaml
```

and your include script would look something like:

```
---
- name: action 1
  command: echo hello world
- name: action 2
  command: echo hello again
```

Note the indentation difference for include scripts - its very important!  YAML can be annoying at times....

Comment: Hmmm, interesting but there is some problems: the included script needs to target different sort of servers (nginx or app) and I can't include a playbook inside another playbook when targeting host group (montigny-servers and bievre-servers) in the first playbook (think about your example with the need to target host in the included script)

Comment: then do 4 tasks group: 
1: biervre-app, include app.yml 
2: bievre-nginx, include nginx.yml
3: mont-app, include app.yml
4: mont-nginx, include nginx.yml

you have minimum code duplication this way

Comment: That's a solution but it's not KISS (Keep It Simple And Stupid) as it requires a lot of files. I prefer ant31's solution. Thanks for the time you spend to answer me.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here is what I think you actually want.

You can use the **serial** keyword to say how many hosts ansible should manage at a single time in a play. So in the example below, ansible would only run the plays on two hosts at a time.

By default, anisble will keep running the plays even if the first two machines fail, so you can use the **max_fail_percentage** keyword to define the percentage of failures acceptable before stopping. In the example below, Ansible will stop if 1 percent of machines failed.

**Source:** http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_delegation.html#rolling-update-batch-size

```
- hosts: app-servers`
  serial: 2 
  max_fail_percentage: 1
  roles: 
   - role: deploy-env
```

And then in your deploy-env role have:

```
- name: remove from LB
  include: remove-server.yml
  delegate_to: paired_nginx_box

  /* app-server tasks */

- name: add to LB
  include: add-server.yml
  delegate_to: paired_nginx_box
```

Comment: I have completed my Ansible playbook snippet.
With the solution you explain, it will not works as playbook will first execute remove-server.yml task on each NGinx server before doing next steps.

Comment: I think the solution could still work, but I need a little bit of clarification. What do the remove-server.yml and the add-server.yml playbooks do? Are you tearing down your nginx boxes and then building new ones?

Comment: Yes you are right, remove-server.yml removes NGinx server from front load balancer, and add-server.yml make it available from LB.
Removing all NGinx servers means killing all instances of application where I need a least one instance up at any time during installation.

Comment: How do you know which nginx servers are pared with which app-servers?

Comment: Good question :)
In fact, since I'm working per location, I don't need to know this information because I disable all NGinx for one location and then update applications on the same location.

Comment: If you knew which nginx hosts were paired to which tomcat hosts, you could solve this using Ansible's delegate_to feature, which lets you delegate a task to another host in your inventory. I changed my answer to show what this would look like

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58320/discussion-between-pfevrier-and-bkan).